# FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultCacheExpiration does not equal to 12 hours

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

In the [Firebase Remote Config Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/remote-config/firebase-remote-config#class_firebase_1_1_remote_config_1_1_firebase_remote_config_1a7cd1c5067fe16f01f5cc3afe98a785bc), it says that the value for DefaultCacheExpiration is a value equal to 12 hours. However, when I try to print the value, it isn't 12 hours. Can anybody else confirm this?

Firebase SDK Version: `7.2.0`, Unity Version: `2020.3.5f1`

Code:

```cs
print(FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultCacheExpiration); // outputs 00:00:04.3200000
print(TimeSpan.FromHours(12)); // outputs 12:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I get 00:00:00.0043200 printed out in the Unity Editor with Firebase 7.1.0.

After updating to Firebase 8.9.0 I now get 12:00:00.